$E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}(-1)^i \frac{1}{i!} = 1?$

Put n balls into n boxes with number (1 to 1).X is the counter of pairs that i-th ball is in i-th box. E(X) = ?.

Attempt:
$P(X=k) = \frac{C_n^k \cdot De_{n-k}}{A_n^n}$, De is the counter of derangements.This equation means selecting k boxes filled with correct balls, then deranging n-k balls in n-k boxes.
Then I got $E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}(-1)^i \frac{1}{i!}$ and the calculation of E is beyond my ability.
I don't know whether this process is wrong or right. By the way, the answer of the question above is 1 deriving from another way.
$$
X_k=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{k-th ball is in the right box}\\
0, & \text{k-th ball is in the wrong box}
\end{cases}
$$
$\because X=\sum X_k, P(X_k = 1) = \frac{1}{n}$
$\therefore E(X) = \sum E(X_k) = n \cdot \frac{1}{n} = 1$
Question:

Can the complex E(X) be calculated to 1?


After re-indexing the outer sum via the substitution $k\gets k+1$, we can rewrite your sum as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}(-1)^i\frac{1}{(k-1)!\cdot i!}= 
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k-1}(-1)^i\frac{1}{k!\cdot i!}.\tag1
$$
I claim that this is exactly the same as
$$
\sum_{d=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{d}(-1)^i\frac{1}{(d-i)!\cdot i!}\tag2
$$
This time, we are re-indexing the double summation, via the substitution $k\gets d-i$. Here's what this really means. The sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k-1}$ ranges over all ordered pairs $(k,i)$ such that $0\le k\le n-1$ and $0\le i+k\le n-1$. These integer points are arranged like a triangle in the plane, and we are summing over each column of the triangular array, then adding up all column sums. Instead, you could sum over the diagonals of the triangle, and then add up all of the diagonal sums. The result is exactly the double sum in $(2)$.
The inner sum of $(2)$ can be evaluated easily. Note that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{d}(-1)^i\frac{1}{(d-i)!\cdot i!}=\frac1{d!}\sum_{i=0}^{d}(-1)^i\binom{d}i=\frac1{d!}(1-1)^d=\begin{cases}1 & d=0\\0 & d > 0\end{cases}
$$
Since the inner sum of $(2)$ evaluates to $1$ when $d=0$ and $0$ otherwise, it follows that the full sum is just $1+0+0+\dots+0=1$.
